# change python list format using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

The list that I am getting is in the following format:

```
arr = ['43f4cc160,2021-06-17,Dan Abramov', ' 1 file changed, 10 insertions(+), 19 deletions(-)', '', 'a0d2d1e1e,2021-06-16,Dan Abramov', ' 1 file changed, 4831 insertions(+), 6450 deletions(-)']
```

and I want to have following format

```
expected_array = ['43f4cc160; 2021-06-17; Dan Ab; 1 file changed, 10 insertions(+), 19 deletions(-)', 'a0d2d1e1e; 2021-06-16; Dan Ab; 2 file changed, 150 insertions(+), 19 deletions(-)'
]
```

I converted python list to numpy array using `np_array = np.array(arr)` but I could not merge two string to make it one like `'43f4cc160,2021-06-17,Dan Abramov', ' 1 file changed, 10 insertions(+), 19 deletions(-)', '',` to `'43f4cc160; 2021-06-17; Dan Ab; 1 file changed, 10 insertions(+), 19 deletions(-)'` so I can split in such way:

`np.char.split(expected_array, ',')`

This way I can have `commit_hash`, `date`, `name`, `file_log`.

Comment: string manipulations are easier in lists than arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj Can you give me a hint on how you will approach when using string manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[i+j for i,j in zip(arr[::2],  arr[1::2])]
```

The idea is to step through the list in pairs, and string concatenate them.

(I haven't tested this.)

Comment: This is what it gave `['43f4cc160 2021-06-17 Dan Ab 1 file changed, 10 insertions(+), 19 deletions(-)', 'a0d2d1e1e 2021-06-16 Dan Ab', ' 1 file changed, 4831 insertions(+), 6450 deletions(-)', '6cbf2a8b3 2021-06-15 Dan Ab 1 file changed, 14303 insertions(+)', 'c0a77029c 2021-06-15 Dan Ab', ' 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)', 'f283d7524 2021-06-15 Dan Ab 1 file changed, 5260 deletions(-)', '03c5314b4 2021-06-15 Dan Ab'
`. There is some string which does not has `.. changed .. insertion(+)`. It's may be there was not such adjacent string. I will dig into it. Thank you.

Comment: It seems like some were not merged.

Answer (score -1):

Multiple strings can be joined together using the "join" method:

```
expected_array = ["".join(arr)]
```

**Edit:**
I misread the question, maybe this works:

```
[arr[i].split(',') + [arr[i+1],] for i in range(0,len(arr),3)]
```

Comment: My bad, I didn't read the question fully. Answer edited.